# Heat produced in collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics, conservation-laws, collision

A 5-gram marble is moving at 5 m/s [N] collides with a 2-gram marble moving at 3 m/s [N].

Final velocity of 2-gram marble: 7 m/s [N]

How would I find the amount of heat produced in this collision?

Info that I've found so far that I know is correct:

Initial momentum of system: 3.10 * 10^-2 Ns

Final momentum: same as initial

Final velocity of 5-gram marble: 3.40 m/s [N]

Comment: Do you know the KE of the marbles before and after the collision?

Comment: No. That's why I'm not sure how to solve this.

Comment: You know the energy before the collision. You also need to know the energy after. The difference is the heat.

Comment: How would one get the energy before?

Comment: Is the collision elastic ? If that's not given and if only the first line is the data of your question, I am afraid only the first 2 points of your "found info" is correct, others cant be found......

Comment: @Shubham The question asks to find heat produced in collision. how can the collision be elastic then?

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, Heat produced = Final Kinetic Energy - Initial Kinetic Energy = $\frac{1}{2}M(V_2^2-V_1^2)+\frac{1}{2}m(v_2^2-v_1^2)=\frac{1}{2}(5 \times 10^{-3})(5^2-(3.40)^2)+\frac{1}{2}(2 \times 10^{-3})(7^2-3^2)$

Comment: According to my physics professor the answer is -6.40*10^-3 J. I tried your method before asking this question but the answer is apparently wrong :/

Comment: So I have no idea how to get the answer mentioned above.

Comment: Is my method logical? Do you see any flaw in the working procedure? Thats whats important. And I may have made a mistake in the units. Please check that as well.

Comment: Your method makes sense and I tried it multiple times. I think it's correct as well, but my physics professor and fellow student got different answers.

Comment: How did you calculate the final velocities?

Comment: That's where he's gone wrong.....those can't be found

Comment: Final velocity of the 2-gram marble was given. p(initial) = p(final)     (3.1*10^-2)=(5*10^-3)v+(2*10^-3)(7)

Comment: You should mention that in your question @Revoltechs

Comment: @Revoltechs Your initial momentum value and the one I calculated using the masses and velocities are different. Check it now.

Comment: @Revoltechs I agree with your Professor. I also agree with Aniket. So even when you are told exactly how to do the problem, you still can't manage it yourself...

Answer (score 0):

Let, $e\ \ (\forall \ \ 0\le e\le1)$ be the coefficient of restitution for collision & $v$ be the velocity of mass $5\ kg$ after collision then we have $$e=\frac{\text{velocity of recess}}{\text{velocity of approach}}=\frac{7-v}{5-3}=\frac{7-v}{2}\tag 1$$
Now, using conservation of momentum in the given direction $$\text{linear momentum before collision}=\text{linear momentum after collision}$$
$$5(5)+2(3)=5(v)+2(7)$$$$\implies v=\frac{17}{5}\ m/s$$
setting the value of $v$ in (1), we get 
$$e=\frac{7-\frac{17}{5}}{2}=\frac{9}{5}=1.8>1$$
but, $0\le e\le1$ i.e. the value of coefficient of restitution ($e$) can never exceed $1$

hence such a collision is not possible or the velocity of $2\ kg$ marble can't be $7\ m/s$ after collision.

Comment: So would you be able to find the 2-gram marble's actual velocity and then determine the heat produced?

Comment: yes, of course, it can be determined, if you provide the feasible velocity of 2 kg marble.

Comment: If I may ask how?

Comment: Alright, if the feasible velocity of $2\ kg$ marble is given/known then actual value of $e$ can be calculated similarly as in the answer then apply set-formula for loss of energy or use conservation of energy. But remember $e$ should be known or calculated

Comment: Remember if feasible velocities of both $2kg$ marble is known then $e$ can be determined or on the other hand if $e$ is known then velocities of both $2kg$ & $5\ kg$ marbles after collision can be calculated so the energy loss can be calculated. You should properly check if some data is wrong or missing.